# Xamarin Android AnimationDrawable

Tags: c#, android, animation

I'm currently trying to make a game project containing custome made frame by frame 2d animations on Xamarin.Android , my problem is that I can't make 2 animations accure one after another, I can't wait for the first animation to stop, it immediately shows the them without waiting for thr first to finish

```
AnimationDrawable animation;
ivPlayer1.SetImageResource(ShootAnimation);
animation = (AnimationDrawable)ivPlayer1.Drawable;
animation.Start();
animation.Stop();
ivPlayer2.SetImageResource(HurtAnimation);
animation = (AnimationDrawable)ivPlayer2.Drawable;
animation.Start();
```

I want the program to wait for the first animation to finish and then make the second one, please help me I'm stuck.
PS I'm pretty new to xamarin android please make sure to make a detailed answer.